# Getting 400 Bad Request Error while accessing twitter data from windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, dotnet-httpclient

I'm developing a windows store app using c# and xaml. I am trying to integrate twitter into it so that user can check his tweets and can tweet from my app.

So when am trying to post a tweet using the below code am getting 400 error.

```
HttpContent hc = new StringContent("Good Morning");
string hw = "HelloWorld";
string dc = "false";    
httpClient.PostAsync(string.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status={0}&display_coordinates={1}", hw, dc), hc);
```

I did this after after successfully getting an oauth_token from twitter. Am getting the same 400 even while accessing the user's tweets using GetAsync().

Kindly help in this regard!!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are not passing `oauth_token` while sending post request.

Comment: How to pass it?? What is the syntax for that?

Comment: Follow [this](https://twitterrt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TwitterRtLibrary/TwitterRtLibrary/TwitterRt.cs), though it uses Twitter API v1. It's deprecated now.

Comment: I dont want to use any third party library for this. I want to do this using httpclient in .net 4.5